# MVC - Use @Html.ActionLInk to fire Ajax to trigger ActionResult

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

I've done a lot of research on this. I can't find anything that really fits my situation. I'm a new programmer. I'm working on getting better with JavaScript but it's my weak spot.

I have two databases - employees and breaks. I attached a picture to make this make more sense:

[image: Screenshot]

The break list from the database is the list you see in the table in the image. The dispatcher dropdown contains all employee names. Drop the name down, hit submit - it adds to the database and displays here. Works great.

Now I'm trying to use @Html.ActionLink to make the names clickable. That needs to fire another JavaScript event to enter DateTime.Now into the TimeCleared field to essentially delete the break from the list.

I'm doing something wrong, though (or a lot of things wrong). Either it doesn't update the database and time stamp that TimeCleared field, I get a "This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third-party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet." error or other errors based on what I try.

Part of the View:

```
<div class="container_lists">
    <div class="container_break col-md-6">
        @*start the break list table*@
        <h5 style="text-align:center">Break List</h5>
        <table class="table-bordered col-lg-12">
            @*populate the table with only those breaks that lack a TimeCleared value*@
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    if (item.TimeCleared == null)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            @*Make each name clickable to fire JavaScript which activates ActionResult DeleteBreak*@
                            <td class="breakIdNumber">
                                @Html.ActionLink(item.DisplayName, "DeleteBreak", new { id = item.BreakId }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Remove from the break list?');" })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            }
        </table>
```

Part of the controller:

```
public ActionResult DeleteBreak(BreakModels breakmodels)
    {
        try
        {
            breakmodels.TimeCleared = DateTime.Now;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { success = true});
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false});
        }
    }
```

Ajax:

```
@*Activate the DeleteBreak ActionResult*@
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#RemoveBreak").click(function () {
            var model = {};
            model.BreakId = Number($("#breakIdNumber").val());
            console.log("model", model);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/DeleteBreak",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(model),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success)
                        window.location.href = "/Home/Index";
                    else
                        alert("Something went wrong");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Something went wrong");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: do you need both actionlink should trigger controller action and javascript function?

Comment: No. All I really need for the actionlink to do is enter DateTime.Now into the break database. If there's an easier way to do it, I'd love it! I just know you can't update the database from actionlink

Comment: is your deletebreak action is hitting?

Comment: No. I can't get it to hit. I either get the To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet error or it just refreshes the index page without hitting it and updating the database

Comment: just check are you able to hit a debugger on removeclick button

Comment: We're actually breaking at this line in the view: @Html.ActionLink(item.DisplayName, "DeleteBreak", new { id = item.BreakId }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Remove from the break list?');" }) (says request was cancelled)

Comment: just try to remove onclick  function and rename DeleteBreak to something else because it tries to match action result and try to hit

Comment: i don't see a `confirm()`. Does this function exist? For debugging, just add `{onclick = "alert()"}` to see if it is actually being hit.

Comment: Hi! I put it up in the view in this line: @Html.ActionLink(item.DisplayName, "DeleteBreak", new { id = item.BreakId }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Remove from the break list?');" }) -- I don't have it in the JavaScript function, though. I'll try that and see if it helps! Thank you!